# MySql - No changes detected

Tags: mysql

Toda vez que altero uma procedure no MySql Workbench e tento gravar (Apply) e eu recebo a seguinte mensagem (No changes detected) ai para contornar o problema eu deleto e recrio a procedure.

Isso é muito chato alguém sabe como resolver?

Abaixo tem duas imagens que mostra que depois de alterar a procedure ele não identifica alteração e não grava.

Obrigado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Posta o código de como você tentava alterar a procedure.

Comment: Coloquei duas imagens, acho que fica mais fácil entender, deve existir alguma opção para desabilitar essa identificação de código alterado, mas eu não consegui encontrar.

Comment: Posta o código não a imagem.

Comment: O código é esse da imagem. um simples select e ele não identifica a alteração.

Comment: O que você esta alterando ??????????

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza talvez você não tenha visto a diferença nas imagens na segunda imagem eu acrescentei uma linha, não importa quantas linhas eu altere ou adicione ele não grava. É isso o que eu estou alterando.

Answer (score 1):

O Mysql apresenta essa mensagem `MySql - No changes detected`, uma vês que o script já tenha sido executado ou nada tenha sido alterado no Script.

O que pode ter acontecido é você ter clicado no Apply uma ver e depois continuar clicando.

Altere seu select e veja que vai se alterado.
E seu `DEFINER=`root`@`%

Abra uma nova guia com seu scrip da procedure da seguinte forma e execute.

```
USE `seu banco`; 
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `procedureTeste`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `seu banco`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `procedureTeste`()
BEGIN

select 'teste';
select 'teste2';
select 'teste3';
select 'teste4';

-- altera o que for preciso e execulta. 
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Já alterei diversas vezes e já cliquei no Apply diversas vezes e a procedure sempre volta para a forma com o conteúdo com qual foi criada a primeira vez, vc sabe se existe uma forma de desativar esta identificação se a procedure foi alterada ou não? Tipo não me interessa se a procedure foi alterada ou não, se eu cliquei no gravar e para gravar e pronto igual o world.

Comment: Tentei com root e também não grava.

Comment: Tente altera através do script .

Comment: Dessa forma funciona mas perde a praticidade que a ferramenta oferece, acredito que o que esteja acontecendo seja um bug do próprio workbench. De qualquer maneira muito obrigado pela ajuda.